# React query devtools not getting imported when using vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-query

I am trying react-query with react with vite as my bundling tool.

When I try to import the ReactQueryDevtools from 'react-query' - I get the following build time error:

[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "react-query/devtools" from "src/main.jsx". Does the file exist?

I assume that ReactQueryDevtools is part of react-query right ?

I did some research and found [this issue](https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/1936)
but in this page some other error is shown.

Please help me guide in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

When I downgraded to v3.39.2 - it started working.
the v4 had some breaking change.

Comment: for v4 you need to use @tanstack/react-query please

Comment: there's an open issue in v4 for this, will be fixed soon.

Comment: this works after using @tanstack query thanks